# .Net Core 2.2 Cookie Authentication Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-2.2

I am pretty new to .net core development and I've got a problem with my .net core web application regards the user authentication by cookie authentication scheme. The problem is, that even tough the cookie is created and I'm logged in properly, I am not able to automatically re-login if the user calls the login page again.

Here is my code for better understanding:

Services configuration

```
services.AddAuthentication()
// Add operator authentication
.AddCookie("OPERATOR_AUTH", o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = "/login";
    o.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    o.AccessDeniedPath = "/denied";
    // Block js cookie access
    o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    // Limit cookies to https connections in production environments
    o.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    // Only allow the cookie on the service pages
    o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
});
services.AddTransient<ILoginService, LoginService>();
```

App configuration

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Use(next => ctx =>
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
      HttpOnly = true
    };
    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(ctx);
    ctx.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,cookieOptions);
    return next(ctx);
});
```

Login Controller

```
/// <summary>
/// The operator login service
/// </summary>
private readonly ILoginService _loginService;
/// <summary>
/// The logger instance received by dependency
/// injection
/// </summary>
private readonly ILogger<LoginController> _logger;

/// <summary>
/// Renders the login view
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[Route("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
  return View(new OperatorLoginModel());
}

/// <summary>
/// Renders the login denied view
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[Route("denied")]
public IActionResult Denied()
{
  return View();
}

/// <summary>
/// Performs a login
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The login model</param>
/// <returns>The result view</returns>
[Route("login")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(OperatorLoginModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }

  var op = await _loginService.IsAuthorizedOperator(model.OperatorCode, model.OperatorPassword);
  if (op != null)
  {
    return await SignInOperator(op);
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Denied", "Login");
}

/// <summary>
/// Performs a logout
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The result view redirection</returns>
[Route("logout")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("OPERATOR_AUTH");
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

/// <summary>
/// Performs the actual sign in by assigning the operator
/// identity to the http context
/// </summary>
/// <param name="op">The operator to sign in</param>
/// <returns>The result view redirection</returns>
private async Task<IActionResult> SignInOperator(Operator op)
{
  var claims = new List<Claim>
  {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,op.Code),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, op.Description)
  };

  var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
  {
    AllowRefresh = true,
    IsPersistent = true,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(30).UtcDateTime,
    IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime
  };

  var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "OPERATOR_AUTH");
  var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

  await HttpContext.SignInAsync("OPERATOR_AUTH", principal, authProperties);
  return RedirectToAction("UserInformation", "Home");
}

/// <summary>
/// Constructor of the login controller
/// </summary>
/// <param name="logger">Logger instance</param>
/// <param name="loginService">Login service</param>   
public LoginController(ILogger<LoginController> logger, ILoginService loginService)
{
  _logger = logger;
  _loginService = loginService;
}
```

What happens is the following:

- The operator can correctly navigate to the login view
- The operator is able to login by entering his or her credentials
- The operator is navigated to the user information view
- The cookie is set in the browser:
  [image]

Now if I log off, the cookie is deleted correctly.

If I don't log of, but refresh the page or renavigate to Home/Login I am not able to receive the User information in the HttpContext:
[image]

Also no automatic authentication is done.

Am I missing something? Anything wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you should be using `services.AddAuthentication("OPERATOR_AUTH")`.

Comment: Hey Kirk, already tried that, same result unfortunately. :/

Comment: What happens if you add `[Authorize]` to `Index` and navigate there?

Comment: Nice, well my user is set then and I am able to react on the login, but wouldn't that cause problems for navigations without an authenticated user? :/

Comment: I tried it and yeah it causes another problem, ... the query gets inacceptable long (appended by dozens of parameters) and the execution ends with 404.15 thrown by the filtering module

Comment: If you want the user to be populated correctly, you need to use `[Authorize]` in one way or another. You can also add `[AllowAnonymous]`, but you'd need to add checks accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, also allowing anonymous obviously solved the looping problem and everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem could be solved by adding the authorization context attribute, aswell as the anonymous context attribute to the controller method as mentioned by kirk larkin.

```
[Route("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "OPERATOR_AUTH")]
public IActionResult Login()
{
  if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("UserInformation", "Home");
  }
  return View(new OperatorLoginModel());
}
```